# Delay in LaunchedEffect break espresso test

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso

I have a test as follows:

```
@get:Rule(order = 1)
val composeRule: ComposeRule = createAndroidComposeRule()

@Test
fun test() {
    composeRule.setContent {
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("test start") }
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
            text = "step 1"
            delay(200)
            text = "step 2"
        })
        Text(text = text, modifier = Modifier.testTag("test"))
    }
    composeRule.onNodeWithTag("test").assertTextEquals("step 1")
}
```

Step 1 is displayed almost instantly, as expected, but test stops on `delay` until crash.

```
androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.android.ComposeNotIdleException: Idling resource timed out: possibly due to compose being busy.
IdlingResourceRegistry has the following idling resources registered:
- [busy] androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.ComposeIdlingResource@a974589
All registered idling resources: Compose-Espresso link
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.EspressoLink_androidKt.rethrowWithMoreInfo(EspressoLink.android.kt:136)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.EspressoLink_androidKt.runEspressoOnIdle(EspressoLink.android.kt:110)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.EspressoLink.runUntilIdle(EspressoLink.android.kt:79)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.waitForIdle(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:336)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.access$waitForIdle(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidComposeUiTestImpl.waitForIdle(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:406)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidComposeUiTestImpl.setContent(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:485)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule.setContent(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:340)
at pl.shvagier.district.ContactTest.test(ContactTest.kt:51)
... 54 trimmed
```

Is something missing in my code? Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

I found that `StandardTestDispatcher` was applied as main in base test. Without time advance there is no surprise that test was stopping. Now there is no exception but still `LaunchedEffect` stops on first suspension point.

Answer (score 1):

Strange that there is no mention about it in docs (or I just haven't met it). LaunchedEffect works on coroutine that has mocked time, so this time needs to advance.

```
 composeRule.mainClock.advanceTimeBy(200)
 // further assertions
```

And everything works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you! I guessed we would need something like InstantTaskExecutorRule for compose but couldn't find anything and was stuck until i found your answer.

Comment: You're welcome :) Actualy ComposeRule is just a typealias for AndroidComposeTestRule<ActivityScenarioRule<ComponentActivity>, ComponentActivity> so no new rule is needed